# qscopedpointer qfile doesn't dynamically writes to file

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, qfile

Have a problem writing to file. 
In my code I have a smart pointer to a file (private class member) and I want to write smth to it.
The problem is that write function writes to a buffer and buffer content writes to file only when I close my app. Why does it happen?

Here is my code:

```
void MyClass::setFile(const QString &name)
{
    m_file.reset(new QFile(name + "temp.txt"));
    m_file->open(QFile::WriteOnly);
}

void writeToFile()
{
    if(m_file != nullptr)
    {
        m_file->write((char *)(&m_str), sizeof(m_str));    // m_str is a struct
        m_file->flush();
    }
}
```